# How do I combine digital audio?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I have two wave files for which I have the digital samples extracted. I need to play both at the same time. How do I combine the two samples to produce the output sample that is both sounds playing together. How is this done for N simultaneous samples? Is it as simple as adding the samples and taking the average?

Comment: I discuss this at the end of this blog post. If you are having trouble with this, reading this post might help you out: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013/05/the-abcs-of-pcm-uncompressed-digital.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply sum the two, and divide by two. 
Indeed, that's the average.

When both samples have the same sample-rate it's really as straightforward as that.

Comment: This also works for an arbitrary number of samples then I take it?

Comment: In your loop you'll probably need to deal with different sample lengths. Loop until the longest of the two samples, and when you reach the end of the shortest, assume value 0 from there on.

Answer (score 4):

Combining sounds (at the same sample rate) just involves an element-wise addition of the two arrays. You do not need to divide by N unless you have an issue with headroom. If the value of the sum exceeds the maximum output level, this will result in clipping, giving an audible distortion.

Unless you have a large N, or a small N where each of your source sounds are normalised to the maximum output level, you should not have a problem with clipping. If you know the waveforms of the signals in advance, you can simply scale each waveform by the same scalar value beforehand so that the output does not clip. Alternatively, if you are rendering the sound offline, you can just sum your waveforms and then normalise the composite signal so it does not clip.

If you are dealing with a live input stream of N sources, you can minimise clipping using a limiter.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression#Limiting

Answer (score 1):

**Combine digital audio by adding the individual samples together.**

There will be a loudness increase when combining several uncorrelated sound sources, [but the relationship between loudness and N number of sources is not linear](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-leveladding.htm). Four simultaneous sounds will be approximately twice as loud as one, not four times as loud. (That's a 6dB increase.)

As you suspected you do need to keep in mind the final output volume when playing back multiple sounds simultaneously but dividing by N when combining N simultaneous sources is not the right way to do so.

The easiest way is to add a volume control to your application. The user will turn down your application when it's too loud. This is simple and usually the correct approach when combining a small number of sounds.

A manual volume control is not the right solution for all problems. For example a first person shooter. Imagine running from a quiet corridor out into a raging gun battle. The sound environment will go from very quiet with a few sound sources to very loud with lots of sound sources. In these cases you'll likely need some form of [automatic gain control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_gain_control).